# Name and parameters of parent function

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to figure out how to get the name and parameters of a parent function.

Example:

```
function foo($a,$b){
  bar();
}

function bar(){
  // Magic Print
}

foo('hello', 'world');
```

Output:

```
foo('hello','world')
```

Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get the information from [debug_backtrace()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php).

```
function bar(){
  $backtrace = debug_backtrace();
  $t = $backtrace[1];
  print $t["function"] . "('" . implode("','", $t["args"]) . "')\n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Thats what I would have done but my head has started getting heavy, time to take a break. I would accept your answer but SO has a time limit!